# How to call an Intent from an activity to another activity but currently i m in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

### Situation is: Through my fragment I m calling a function which is in another activity. And now I want that, from that function I intent to a completely different activity.

How can this be done?

```
class DemoFragAct extends Fragment{
...
calling();
}    
class demoActivity extends Activity{
...
void calling(){
...
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),newAct.class);
startActivity(i);
}
}
class newAct extends Activity{...}
```

Null pointer exception is coming up.

Comment: what is the problem to make intent from current activity to another one ,after complete your method ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, simply start the new activity from your function, calling the parent activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourNewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

declare a member variable mContext at your base fragment.

```
protected Context mContext;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);
mContext = context ;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
super.onDetach();
mContext = null;
}
```

So you can use your context variable anywhere without having a direct coupling with your holder activity

```
private void startSecondActivity(){
//your code above
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hint your fragment must be attached to its activity enable you to navigate to another activity

Comment: sorry for mistake replace getActivity()   by  mContext

Answer (score 0):

And as i wrote you as comment before ,with code must be some like this:

```
private void yourMethod(){

  //your code above
  Intent intent = new Intent(demoActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: please see the above editted question, hope i m able to make you understand this time.

Comment: chek my edit, and can i ask you how do you get calling() which is in your activity , are you use callback?